# Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" is null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a simple servlet to fetch data from JSP and creating a simple **session** But every time I submit the response in JSP it shows **null pointer exception**

My **web.xml** file is properly mapped

Attaching code snippet for my Servlet class and JSP form

```
//doGet Method Java

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{  
   
    try{  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
      
    String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
    out.print("Welcome "+n);
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("uname",n);
    out.close();  

 }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
}
```

}

```
// JSP File

<form method="post" action="forgotPassword" >
<input type="text" name="userName" >
<input type="submit">[Error output of eclipse console][1]
```

Comment: You are using a POST  method in your form.  In your Servlet,  the doGet method is called  when it receives a GET request.  You could put some debug statements in your code to help you.

Comment: 1. As rickz said, use [doPost](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-), not doGet.  2. Remove your try/catch, and restore `throws ServletException, IOException` to your method declaration.  That should allow you to see the full stack trace of your exception.  The code you’re showing us doesn’t call HttpSession.getAttribute(String) at all, so I expect some other code is responsible for the problem.  The stack trace will tell us where that code is.

Comment: You can find the stack trace here https://ibb.co/PF4f8Zh

Comment: Please show us the ForgotPassword.java file.  Post the code like you did in your question.